# Why do app windows not extend to bottom of screen?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I run OS X 10.10.3 and occasionally notice (must've been there forever, it's not *very* obtrusive, but occasionally annoying) that windows which are maximized but not in full screen leave some space at the bottom. I changed the desktop background to a garish green and added the red frame to illustrate the issue (it still gets muted by the window's drop shadow, so it's not always easy to see in practice).

**Exhibit A**
[image]

**Exhibit B**
[image]

I guess my question is whether this is intentionally designed like this and if so, what the reason could be and how to avoid this. It seems nonsensical to me.

Comment: This bugs me even more with the gap between the window top and the menu bar when you are using dark mode. I'm guessing it's a bug and some retina screens make this bug even worse. Have you tried using a tool like [Xscope](http://xscopeapp.com) to get an exact pixel count?

Comment: I'm assuming you have the dock on auto-hide? It might be leaving that gap to account for the dock reappearing - when the dock is always present, you cannot resize a window past the top of the dock (when the dock is the bottom).

Comment: As @tubedogg says, you need a bit of space for the Dock to recognise you want it to spring up - always seems to be about 5 pixels. If it makes us Mac users feel any better… Windows does it too if you hide the task bar ;)

Comment: Perhaps, but I wonder if this is necessary. Detecting whether the cursor is within the bottom 5 pixels rows is independent on whether those are occupied by some app's window or the desktop. Yes, it might get difficult to click on something at the window's bottom if the dock would get in the way, but how often does that happen? When I move the cursor within the bottom 2% of the screen, I aim for the dock in 99% of the cases, and I expect I'm not the only one. I just don't get it.

Comment: My guess is it's less about difficulty of detection and more about the dock not constantly un-hiding when your cursor strays to the bottom of a window.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141800/gap-at-the-bottom-of-maximized-windows

Comment: I found some solutions for this and posted them to http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/141800/25698